# Simple custom UI in Maya using Python

Tags: python, maya

Hi I am learning about creating custom UI for Maya using Python. I am trying to achieve few things which I am unable to do. I searched around but couldn't find my answers.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def main():

    cmds.window(title='Test Window')
    cmds.columnLayout()
    cmds.textFieldGrp('obj1', label='Name', text ="Please enter your name")
    cmds.textFieldGrp('obj2', label='Address', text = "Please enter your address")
    cmds.rowLayout(nc=3)
    cmds.button(label="Lock", width=100, c='disable_texts()')
    cmds.button(label="Edit", width=100, c='change_texts()')
    cmds.button(label="Reset", width=100, c='default()')
    cmds.showWindow()

def disable_texts():
    # disable the text fields

def change_texts():
    # enable the text fields

def default():
   # change the text fields back to default ie like above
```

Comment: What's the question/problem?

Comment: As posted you'll never be able to update the texts, since you are not storing the name of the texts anywhere.  'textFieldGroup -e obj1' might not work, since you can't be sure that you haven't already got an 'obj1' somewhere else. Capture the result of the command into a variable and use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might answer your question, if I understand..

```
cmds.window(title='Test Window')
cmds.columnLayout()
cmds.textFieldGrp('obj1', label='Name', text ="Please enter your name")
cmds.textFieldGrp('obj2', label='Address', text = "Please enter your address")
cmds.rowLayout(nc=3)
cmds.button(label="Lock", width=100, c=disable_texts)
cmds.button(label="Edit", width=100)
cmds.button(label="Reset", width=100)
cmds.showWindow()

def disable_texts(*args):
    #The e=True is for edit, so I'm 'editing' 'obj1' which is the name of the textFieldGrp
    cmds.textFieldGrp('obj1', e=True, enable=False)
```

As a side note, it's better to pass the function object to the `command` flag. Check [this](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/PyMel/ui.html#function-name-as-string) out if you're unsure why. As for the `cmds` functions you should check the docs to see what other commands there are.

Comment: Same issue as here -- use commands directly for the callbacks instead of strings.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215582/importing-pyc-into-existing-python-script

Answer (score 1):

After you made your experiences with layouting UIs with the Maya builtin possibilities I recommend you to setup PyQT for Maya.

If you are using Maya Version below 2014, than you need to install the compiled PyQt from here: http://nathanhorne.com/?s=pyqt

Since Maya integrated PyQT with 2014 (therefore 2015 also) you don't need to install anything for this version.

Here some starting tutorials:
http://zurbrigg.com/maya-python/category/pyqt-projects-for-maya

Have fun!!!